# What happened to Prime Elizabeth after Burial at Sea?

Tags: bioshock-infinite, bioshock-series

At the end of the Burial at Sea DLC, we see that:

> Elizabeth dies protecting Sally and sets the events of 1st Bioshock

So does that mean based on the ending of both the Burial at Sea DLCs.

Are both **Prime** Comstock/Booker and **Prime** Elizabeth dead?

Comment: In general, this stack does not try to speculate on what the developers intended.  You might consider asking this question on the Science Fiction and Fantasy stack, as their rules are less strict on this.  If you want the question migrated, you could ask a moderator to do it (flag post with a custom reason, "please migrate to SFF.SE").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll make this as simple as I can.

There is no Prime Comstock and Prime Elizabeth, as there are multiple Elizabeths and Bookers and calling one of them Prime is a bad idea.

**Essentially the Elizabeth from *Infinite* and *BaS Ep1* is dead at the start of Episode 2**. The Elizabeth that we are playing as sees her other dead self.

The Elizabeth that that we are playing as is from a different timeline where she feels regret for leaving Sally in the vent to die. She came to this timeline to rescue our Sally from the same fate. She looked through all of the tears and found the one instance where she had killed Comstock and died herself.

Yes, all Bookers are dead because the one that went down to Rapture in order to find his daughter is dead. All of the rest were drowned at the end of Infinite.

I'm also adding the definitive video that I've found that explains the entire story. It's a GREAT watch: [Here you go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSGGl9G5Jnw)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you’re saying an Elizabeth let Sally die in her timeline, then came to our BaS Ep2 timeline to save Sally there.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Yes, there is a scene in Ep2 where Elizabeth is haunted by images of Sally burning in the vents, solidifying that Elizabeth did not save Sally in that timeline.

Comment: I made some edits to try and clarify. Feel free to revert if I messed up any of the details.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Nope looks good. Trying to keep the ending of Burial At Sea simple is really hard so this clears it up a bit.

Comment: I finally understood Bioshock Infinite's ending and was pleased with myself and then Burial at Sea had to push me off the damn boat with its ending... Great answer!

Comment: @NikhilEshvar Yeah you're not alone with that! It's a fantastic game I'm glad you enjoyed it!